# Recommended way to handle empty vs existing DB in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run `M/Monit` (https://mmonit.com/) in a docker container and found this `Dockerfile`: https://github.com/mlebee/docker-mmonit/blob/master/Dockerfile

I'm using it with a simple `docker-compose.yml` in my test environment:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mmonit:
        build: .
        ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        #volumes:
            #- ./db/:/opt/mmonit/db/
```

It does work, but I want to extend the `Dockerfile` so that the path `/opt/mmonit/db/` is exported as a volume. I'm struggling to implement the following behaviour:

- When the volume mapped to `/opt/mmonit/db/` is empty (for example on first setup) the files from the install archive should be written to the volume. The `db` folder is part of the archive.
- When the database file `/opt/mmonit/db/mmonit.db` already exists in the volume, it should not be overwritten in any circumstances.

I do have an idea how to script the required operations / checks in bash, but I'm not even sure if it would be better to replace the `ENTRYPOINT` with a custom start script or if it should be done by modifying the `Dockerfile` only.
That's why I ask for the recommended way.

Comment: Why you have build instruction in compose file?

Comment: Don't use mmonit inside Docker. Let docker handle it via resources: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources Also I don't think there is any way to do what you are asking. when you add a volume as in your example what you are really doing is MOUNTING. It does not overwrite any exist data but the existing data will not be available. You could do what I have done in the past and that is to mount to a different location and then using a custom script to copy or sync the data.

Comment: @GintsGints why not have a build in a compose file? It's great for creating dev compose files.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs imho he can use existing image instead.

Comment: @GintsGints I see your point and agree. David provided a solid answer though I still would not use monit. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the strategy you lay out is the correct path; it's essentially what the standard Docker Hub database images do.

The image you link to is a community image, so you shouldn't feel particularly bound to that image's decisions.  Given the lack of any sort of license file in the GitHub repository you may not be able to copy it as-is, but it's also not especially complex.

Docker supports two "halves" of the command to run, the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.  `CMD` is easy to provide on the Docker command line, and if you have both, [Docker combines them together](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) into a single command.  So a very typical pattern is to put the actual command to run (`mmmonit -i`) as the `CMD`, and have the `ENTRYPOINT` be a wrapper script that does the required setup and then `exec "$@"`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am the Docker entrypoint script

# Create the database, but only if it does not already exist:
if ! test -f /opt/mmonit/db/mmonit.db; then
  cp -a /opt/monnit/db_base /opt/monnit/db
fi

# Replace this script with the CMD
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, then, you'd specify both the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`:

```sh
# ... do all of the installation ...

# Make a backup copy of the preinstalled data
RUN cp -a db db_base

# Install the custom entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/monit/bin
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

# Standard runtime metadata
USER monit
EXPOSE 8080
# Important: this must use JSON-array syntax
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/monit/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
# Can be either JSON-array or bare-string syntax
CMD /opt/monit/bin/mmonit -i
```

I would definitely make these kind of changes in a Dockerfile, either starting `FROM` that community image or building your own.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked perfectly fine for me. I just ran into one issue where the operation `RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh` failed even when I used absolut paths. I got around that by copying the `entrypoint.sh` to `/`. I don't understand why this is, but I'm totally fine with having the entrypoint script on the root level.

Comment: Regarding your comment on whether I can copy and or modify the Dockerfile from the public community repo. I have to admin that I didn't even think about that, even though I treat others intellectual property seriously.

Comment: I rated the decision to publicly share the Dockerfile as a contribution. Just thinking: In case I would like to fork the community repo and use your solution here together with my own modifications, would it be enough to ask for your permission?

Comment: In general Stack Overflow content is [under a Creative Commons license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow); see also the "Legal" link in the page footer below.